# create a pagination with shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, pagination, shortcode

on my Wordpress site, I created CPT shortcodes, I want there to be 6 posts per page. But when I have more posts, I want the most anician to be visible and to set up a pagination.

how can I add that?

Here is my current code:

```
    function diwp_create_shortcode_newprojects_post_type(){
 
    $args = array(
                    'post_type'      => 'projets',
                    'posts_per_page' => '6',
                    'category_name' => 'neufs',
                    'publish_status' => 'published',
                 );
  
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
  
    if($query->have_posts()) :
  
        while($query->have_posts()) :
  
            $query->the_post() ;
         $content = wpautop( get_the_content() );
                     
  /*     $result .= '<div class="post-item">';
        $result .= '<div class="post-poster">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
        $result .= '<div class="post-name">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
        $result .= '<div class="post-desc">' . get_the_content() . '</div>'; 
        $result .= '</div>'; */
   
     $result .= '<div class="block-actu-list"><a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() .'"> <div class="img-actu">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large') . '</div> </a><div class="legend">' . get_the_title() . '</div></div>';
  
        endwhile;
  
        wp_reset_postdata();
  
    endif;    
  
    return $result;            
  }
  
  add_shortcode( 'newprojects-listed', 'diwp_create_shortcode_newprojects_post_type' );
```

----------------- Edit -----------------

With @Saqib Amin 's answer I'm trying this, is this correct ?

```
  // CPT shortcode HomePage
function diwp_create_shortcode_project_post_type(){
  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array(
                  'post_type'      => 'projets',
                  'posts_per_page' => '10',
                  'paged' => $paged,
                  'category_name' => '',
                  'publish_status' => 'published',
               );

  $query = new WP_Query($args);

  if($query->have_posts()) :

      while($query->have_posts()) :

          $query->the_post() ;
       $content = wpautop( get_the_content() );
                   
/*     $result .= '<div class="post-item">';
      $result .= '<div class="post-poster">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
      $result .= '<div class="post-name">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
      $result .= '<div class="post-desc">' . get_the_content() . '</div>'; 
      $result .= '</div>'; */
 
   $result .= '<div class="block-actu-list"><a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() .'"> <div class="img-actu">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large') . '</div> </a><div class="legend">' . get_the_title() . '</div></div>';

      endwhile;

      wp_reset_postdata();

  endif;    

  return $result;            
}

add_shortcode( 'project-listed', 'diwp_create_shortcode_project_post_type' );
```

Comment: Please see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. According to this, I just have to add : $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; and then 'paged' => $paged,' in args ?